# объясните где создается еще один экземпляр

Tags: java, android

Убрал из кода всё что не по делу.

входной класс:

```
  public class One  extends AppCompatActivity implements IGetDialog{
      GameOverFragment gameOverFragment;
      MainGamePanel mainGamePanel;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           gameOverFragment = new GameOverFragment();
           mainGamePanel = (MainGamePanel) findViewById(R.id.surface);
           mainGamePanel.setInterface(this);
      }

      public void showDialog() { 
         gameOverFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"GameOverFragment");       
       }

     }
```

Класс в котором мне нужно было вызывать диалогФрагмент, но этого нельзя сделать , для вызова диалог фрагмент нужно наследоваться от AppCompatActivity. Поэтому создан интерфейс, mGetDialog экземпляр интерфейса, в который передается класс One ( Что тут происходит? mGetDialog становится экземпляром класса One, в котором доступны только методы интерфейса? Или это не экземпляр, а ссылка на экземпляр One уже созданный системой? разжуюйте пожалуйста этот момент)

```
      public class MainGamePanel  extends extends SurfaceView {
             IGetDialog mGetDialog;

             public void setInterface(IGetDialog name) {
                 mGetDialog = name;
             }

             public void CollisionTrue() {
                mGetDialog.showDialog();
             }


         }
```

В этом классе я пытаюсь получить gameOverFragment, который будет показан из MainGamePanel. Но на деле получается, что я имею ДиалогФрагмент из класса One, а в MainGamePanel показывается ДиалогФрагмент из того экземпляра класса One, который создался в mGetDialog. Как решить эту проблему? И почему это разные объекты ДиалогФрагмента?

```
class MainThread extends Thread implements Callback {

    One one;

    MainThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, MainGamePanel gamePanel) {
        super();
        one = new One;
        one.gameOverFragment.registerCallBack(this); // но gameOverFragment = null;


    }

    @Override
    public void callingBack() {
       //код для обратного вызова
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        // код выполняемый в доп.потоке
    }
}
```

Ну и сам класс диалога , с экземпляром которого работаю

```
public class GameOverFragment extends DialogFragment implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener{
    private View form = null;
    Callback callback;


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View form = getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
                .inflate(R.layout.gameoverfragment, null);

        return dialog;

    }


    public void registerCallBack(Callback callback){
        this.callback = callback;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface unused) {
        super.onDismiss(unused);
        callback.callingBack();
    }


}
```

Comment: Можно сделать static gameOverFragment, но хочется понять механизм работы. Еще я добавил в интерфейс геттер, который возвращает фрагмент. и в классе MainThread,создав экземпляр MainGamePanel и получив через него mGetDialog и вызвав после геттер , я получил нужный мне экземпляр ДиалогФрагмента. Вопрос сводится к тому, что мне нужно понять что я передал через интерфейс mainGamePanel.setInterface(this)? Мне сказали это только ссылка на экземпляр, но на деле видно, что это новый экземпляр. И просьба написать, как правильно гуглить вопросы касательно работы java на этом уровне, который обсуждается.

Comment: Создавать активити через конструкторы нельзя. Т.е. можно, компилятор позволит, но это будет просто экземпляр класса, а не системный процесс. Вам надо как-то передать ссылку на активити, которую система запустила, в поток.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Экземпляр Вы создаёте сами строкой `one = new One;`
Оператор `new` как раз для этого и предназначен.
Вы ведь отдали ссылку на `One` классу `MainGamePanel` добавьте туда геттер и сможете через него обратиться:

```
public class One  extends AppCompatActivity implements IGetDialog{

    // по логике этот метод должен быть объявлен в IGetDialog
    @Override
    public GameOverFragment getDialog() { 
       return gameOverFragment;  
    }

}    

public class MainGamePanel  extends extends SurfaceView {
         IGetDialog mGetDialog;

         public void setInterface(IGetDialog name) {
             mGetDialog = name;
         }

         public IGetDialog getInterface() {
             return mGetDialog;
         }

     } 

class MainThread extends Thread implements Callback {

    MainThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, MainGamePanel gamePanel) {
        gamePanel.getInterface().getDialog.registerCallBack(this);
   }
```

}

Вообще у Вас структура кода сильно запутанная, оттого и непонятки.

Comment: А вот немного прозрел вроде. Выходит я в MainThread создаю новый экземпляр One (хотя мне вот  ЮрийСПб говорит, что я не мог в конструкторе новый экземпляр создать..) и новый экземпляр изменяю. А когда вызываю через MainGamePanel , то это первый экземпляр и в нем нет тех изменений , что я сделал. Так? И когда я передаю ссылку на One в MainGamePanel , то нового экземпляра не создается. Так?

Comment: ЮрийСПб пишет что так Вы создаёте новый экземпляр, но он не является ни полноценной, работающей `Activity`, ни тем более тем же экземпляром, в котором Вы что-то делали. Вам нужно внимательно перечитать начало учебника по java и понять что такое класс, объект и ссылка на объект, как объекты создаются и как получить объект по ссылке. Оператор `new` однозначно создаёт новый объект. Передача параметром в метод, присвоение одной переменной другой создаёт копию ссылки на тот же самый объект.